# How to know if google routes api has found no routes?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-routes-api

I am trying the new google routes api, I tried 2 edge cases:

- origin and destination are 2 points in the sea
- origin and destination are 2 points in the land but are very close (<10 meters)

In first case, this is the request for `computeRoutes`:

```
{
    "origin": {
        "location": {
            "latLng": {
                "latitude": 33.29970432790808,
                "longitude": 35.070910203529856
            }
        }
    },
    "destination": {
        "location": {
            "latLng": {
                "latitude": 33.299996850855344,
                "longitude": 35.070292786688945
            }
        }
    },
    "travelMode": "DRIVE",
    "computeAlternativeRoutes": false,
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "units": "IMPERIAL"
}
```

and this is the request for `computeRouteMatrix`:

```
{
    "origins": [
        {
            "waypoint": {
                "location": {
                    "latLng": {
                        "latitude": 33.29970432790808,
                        "longitude": 35.070910203529856
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "destinations": [
        {
            "waypoint": {
                "location": {
                    "latLng": {
                      "latitude": 33.29970432790808,
                      "longitude": 35.070910203529856
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The responses are respectively:

```
{}
```

and

```
[
    {
        "originIndex": 0,
        "destinationIndex": 0,
        "status": {},
        "condition": "ROUTE_NOT_FOUND"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the `computeRoutes` returns no useful information in this case, just an empty json map, opposed to the `computeRouteMatrix` which returns for each origin/dest pair a `condition` flag indicating that no route was found.

1- Can I reliably depend on empty response for `computeRoutes` to  know that no route was found? I can't find this case in the docs.

2- Same question for `computeRouteMatrix`, I want to know if this(the condition param in the response) is a reliable way to know whether no route was found at all

3- How do I know which fields in the response to these 2 calls are nullable or not? I want to create an interface for this api in dart, which has sound null safety, so I need to know when a variable can be nullable in the response. I could find the required params of the request in the docs, but the docs don't mention anything about which params in the response (for both apis) are nullable.

Note: In the above requests I am using the mask "*" to return all possible response data

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much on the right track:

1- The more reliable indicator that `computeRoutes` found no routes would the that the `routes` field is missing. I would not recommend relying on an *entirely empty* response, the Routes API may introduce additional fields in the future that *may* be present even when no `routes` are returned (e.g. Directions API returns [`available_travel_modes`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsResponse-available_travel_modes)) sometimes).

2- For `computeRouteMatrix`, the [`condition`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/reference/rest/v2/TopLevel/computeRouteMatrix#response-body) response field seems to be *the* reliable way to know whether a route was found or not (for each element).

3- In terms of which fields in the response are nullable, IIUC all fields are nullable, at least in theory. In practice, `computeRouteMatrix` responses will probably always have at least a non-empty array of elements *unless* the request is rejected (invalid request values, bad/missing API key, etc.).